# How do I stop Netflix from losing sync between audio and video?

Tags: windows-10, audio, video, video-streaming, netflix

When I play Netflix on my Windows 10 computer, the audio gradually becomes desynchronized from the video. This happens on any browser, and on the Netflix Windows Store app.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix this by going to “Control Panel -> Sound” then double-clicking my speakers from the list, then clicking the advanced tab, and unchecking “Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device.”

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but for me, as soon as I changed to the Netflix Win 10 app instead of the web page, it resolved itself. My guess is that the app has better access to get the current Bluetooth delay, so it can sync with it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my audio lagged behind 200ms due to the BT headset I was using. I ended up installing Kodi with the Netflix addon, which allows to sync audio/video.. and it works!

Hope this helps someone in the same situation

Answer (score -1):

I tried all I found on the web, adapting my default browser - firefox - as indicated without success. When - in desperation - I made Edge my default browser the problem vanished and never came back!
So my recommendation is to try to swich to Edge default browser to watch Netflix before changing settings on your preferred browser.
I hope this helps people having the same problem!